# Sniffer Snippet to allow brackets on new line

Tags: php, phpcodesniffer

Is there a codesniffer snippet which allows/forces { } to be put on newlines for every function/method?

Basically, forcing something like this:

```
if (TRUE)
{
     // Code logic
}
else
{
    // Code Logic
}
```

And

```
public function test()
{
     // Code logic
}
```

Comment: Have they to exist in constructs like `if (true) do1(); else do2();` or shall they only put into newlines if they exist?

Comment: I already have another snippet in place which forces the body to be always put between brackets. So yep, they have to exist

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is a ready one. It's called `OpeningFunctionBraceBsdAllmanSniff` and you can find it under `/path/to/CodeSniffer/Standards/Generic/Sniffs/Functions`. But that's only for functions' declarations.

For control structures you can take the `/path/to/Standards/Squiz/Sniffs/ControlStructures/ControlSignatureSniff.php` and tweak the pattern array from

```
protected function getPatterns()
{
    return array(
            'try {EOL...} catch (...) {EOL',
            'do {EOL...} while (...);EOL',
            'while (...) {EOL',
            'for (...) {EOL',
            'if (...) {EOL',
            'foreach (...) {EOL',
            '} else if (...) {EOL',
            '} elseif (...) {EOL',
            '} else {EOL',
           );

}//end getPatterns()
```

to, i.e.

```
protected function getPatterns()
{
    return array(
            'try {EOL...} catch (...) {EOL',
            'do {EOL...} while (...);EOL',
            'while (...) {EOL',
            'for (...) {EOL',
            'if (...)EOL{',              // that's what you need
            'foreach (...) {EOL',
            '} else if (...) {EOL',
            '} elseif (...) {EOL',
            '} elseEOL{',               // and this
           );

}//end getPatterns()
```

If you need to apply the same rule to other control structure, you can go the same way, by changing the patterns in the array.

**Update:** one cleaner solution would be, of course, to write your own class which extends the above and overrides the the `getPatterns()` method.

Comment: This does not seem to work if the bracket is indented

`Expected "if (...)\n{"; found "if (...)\n\t\t{"`

Comment: @MikulasDite you may want to convert your tabs into spaces. If you, for some reason don't want to do this in your editor/IDE, PHPCS can do it for you. You need to set the the corresponding option, i.e. your tabs are 4 spaces: `$ phpcs --config-set tab_width 4`, as it's [described in the documentation](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.php.php-codesniffer.config-options.php)

Comment: This solved the tab problem for me: `'if (...)EOL...{'` (edited Havelock's solutions)